# Hadoop and Cassandra integration - substituting HDFS with Cassandra

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, hdfs

I want to efficiently develop a Hadoop job using Cassandra as input and output.
As I know MapReduce jobs in Hadoop uses HDFS to store intermediate results.

**Is it possible to make Hadoop store intermediate results in Cassandra File System? If yes then how to achieve that?**

I wonder if it possible to completely disable HDFS if I am using Hadoop only Cassandra as underlying data storage system.

I am using Cassandra 2.0.11 and Hadoop 1.0.4 (If the above is possible only in Hadoop 2.x I would also apreciate that information)

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-file-system-design?

Comment: I omitted it somehow, thanks Don!

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: I think yes - it shows how to configure Hadoop to use Cassandra File System

Comment: Which approach is better in case described in my main question? Store intermadiate files in HDFS or CFS?

Comment: I noticed that CFS comes only with Datastax Enterprise which is unfortunately not free...